# How can I separate units from number (like 30px = 30 + "px") in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm looking for a way to separate number from its unit - like 400px (400 + px), 30em (30 + em), 5% (5 + %) etc.

It's perhaps something simple but I couldn't find any pre-made functions in PHP manual to do that.

Let's say that I have this:

```
$variable = "50px";
// and this is what I need:
$result = array(50, 'px');
```

Comment: I don't know regex and it's complicated to find good formula.

Comment: Then learn, you'll love it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try This

```
<?php
$str = '400px';
$arr = preg_split('/(?<=[0-9])(?=[a-z]+)/i',$str);                                                               
print_r($arr);
```

than you will get array like

```
Array
(
    [0] => 400
    [1] => px
)
```

and now you can get

```
  echo  $arr[0]; //for 400
  echo $arr[1];  // for px
```

[**Codepad**](http://codepad.org/1WhmfOvA)

Comment: Works excellent :) Thanks! When I see regular expressions I don't understand usage of a single character unfortunately but it's a powerful thing.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer this method:

```
$arr[0] = intval($str);   
$arr[1] = substr($str, strlen($arr[0]));
```